# A issue about the class member access while the nominated data member is of reference type

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Test{
    Test(int& r):rf(r){

    }
    int& rf;
};
int main(){
   int a = 0;
   Test t(a);
   decltype(t.rf) b;  
}
```

Consider the above code, the compiler complains such a code is [ill-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/EzEqEx), because `b` is of reference type and it's not be initialized. However according to the following rules, I wonder why the type of `b` is a reference type?
[dcl.type.simple#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4)

> For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as follows:
>
> > - if e is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), decltype(e) is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;
> > - otherwise, if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or **an unparenthesized class member access**, decltype(e) is **the type of the entity named by e**. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;

And according to what the paragraph [expr.ref#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#4) says:

> If E2 is declared to **have type “reference to T”**, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; **the type of E1.E2 is T**. Otherwise, one of the following rules applies.

It means that the type of `t.rf` is `int`. I have to say it is vague that the section [expr.ref] does not say, `E1.E2` is still a reference(what is the exactly entity the expression `E1.E2` denotes?). It just say such an expression is `lvalue` and its type is what the reference refer to.

I only find a special rule in [expr], that is:
[expr#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#5)

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T **prior to any further analysis**. **The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference**, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression. [ Note: Before the lifetime of the reference has started or after it has ended, the behavior is undefined (see [basic.life]).  — end note ]

Does it mean that before analyzing the expression `t.rf`, since `rf` has the type “reference to T”, it should be adjusted to `int` and such an expression, namely `rf` designates `a` to which it refers.

So, According to these above rules, the result of `decltype(t.rf)` should be `int`, why the compiler consider it as `int&`?

Answer (score 7):

> > if E2 is declared to have type “reference to T”, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; the type of E1.E2 is T. Otherwise, one of the following rules applies.
>
> It means that the type of t.rf is int.

Indeed, it means that the type of the **expression** `t.rf` is int (and category is lvalue). But the type of the named **entity** - which is the class member - is still lvalue reference to int and hence that is the type given by `decltype(t.rf)`.

E2 is defined in the context as such:

> [expr.ref]
>
> Abbreviating postfix-expression.id-expression as E1.E2, ...

Entity is defined as:

> [basic.pre]
>
> An entity is a value, object, reference, structured binding, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, or pack.

The list of entities doesn't include expressions. E2 is not an entity. It is an expression that names (denotes) an entity.

Comment: Do you mean that the meaning of `decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e` is , `E2` is actually the entity named by `E1.E2`?

Comment: @jackX `E2 is the entity named by E1.E2?` No, E2 is not an entity. E2 is an id-expression, which names an entity. In this case it names a class member which happens to be a reference.

Comment: why the named entity by the expression `E1.E2` is the class member, which rule in the standard says that. Please point it out. Thanks.