# what is the entity does an expression "E1.E2" denote when E2 is of reference type

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct Test{
  Test(int& v):rf(v){}
  int& rf;
  int obj;
};
int main(){
  int i = 0;
  Test t{i};
  t.rf = 1;
  t.obj = 1;
}
```

According to these rules for [class member access](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#4):

> If E2 is declared to have type “reference to T”, **then E1.E2 is an lvalue; the type of E1.E2 is T**. Otherwise, one of the following rules applies.

The clause only says what `value category` and type the expression are when `E2` is of reference type. It's unlike these clauses that apply for the expression `E1.E2`, where `E2` is not of reference type. which discuss what the entity denoted by such an expression implicitly. Such as:

> If E2 is a static data member and the type of E2 is T, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; **the expression designates the named member of the class**.

> If E2 is a non-static data member and the type of E1 is “cq1 vq1 X”, and the type of E2 is “cq2 vq2 T”, **the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression**.

> If it refers to a static member function and the type of E2 is “function of parameter-type-list returning T”, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; **the expression designates the static member function**.

> Otherwise, if E1.E2 refers to a non-static member function and the type of E2 is “function of parameter-type-list cv ref-qualifier <sub>opt</sub>
> returning T”, then E1.E2 is a prvalue. **The expression designates a non-static member function**.

The section [expr.ref] says all the situations that what the entity denoted by `E1.E2` except that when `E2` is of reference type.

[basic.lval#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#2)

> The result of a glvalue is the **entity denoted by the expression**.

Such as `t.obj`, Because `obj` is a non-static non-reference data member(one of the following rules applies, **the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression**), hence The entity denoted by the expression `t.obj` is the member `obj` of the object `t`, namely the subobject `obj` within `t`, So the result of such lvalue is such an entity.

However, For the example `t.rf`, there's no any quote in [expr.ref] points out what's the entity denoted by this expression? when applying assignment operation to such lvalue `t.rf = 1;`, `t.rf` as a glvalue, which should be determined which entity it denotes, then the right operand will modify the value of the entity. So, My question is:

**what's the entity the expression `t.rf` denotes, which rule in the standard says that?**

Comment: Is it the same question as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663887/a-issue-about-the-class-member-access-while-the-nominated-data-member-is-of-refe)?

Comment: @LouisGo Not the same question, the linked question shall be based on this question, that is, what the entity denoted by `E1.E2`. we should firstly determine what the entity is, then we can determine what the type is when apply `decltype(x)` to such an entity.

Comment: @PasserBy Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @jackX There is no mention of "*entity*" in the [expr.ref](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref) page you link. The "*expression*" `t.rf` is covered by the (4) you quoted at the top (`rf` is a reference, so `t.rf` is an lvalue of type `int`). But you'll need to explain what you mean by "*entity denoted by the expression*" since that's not obvious.

Comment: @dxiv According to bullet [expr.ref#4], the expression `t.rf` is lvalue, Right? According to the rule `The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression.`, what's the entity denoted by the expression `t.rf`(what's the result of `t.rf`), I can't find it in [expr.ref].

Comment: @jackX Note that "*entity*" is a general term that includes "*values*". In that context, the result is the value of the expression, which was already determined to be of `int` type. Same as, for example, the "*entity*" denoted by `std::log(3.14) + 1` being a `double` value.

Comment: @dxiv NO, that's not the definition for the result of `glvalue` but for the result of prvalue. Definition for glvalue  is `A glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the **identity of an object, bit-field, or function**.` and  such an entity is `is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, or parameter pack.`   ----- **The result of a prvalue is the value that the expression stores into its context. **

Comment: @jackX That's irrelevant here. You started this post by talking about expressions, and in that context an expression must be evaluated before worrying about what "*entity*" it "*denotes*". If that's not the context you meant, then this looks like a duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663887/a-issue-about-the-class-member-access-while-the-nominated-data-member-is-of-refe).

Comment: @dxiv So, what do you think the result is when evaluating a glvalue?

Comment: @jackX *As expressions* all of `t.obj`, `t.rf` and `t.obj + t.rf` have an `int` value (though different categories). But maybe I misunderstand your question, so I'll leave it to the real language lawyers.

Comment: @dxiv I have modified the last part of this question. what I asked is not the `value` such an expression possesses. Instead, a lvalue that appears in the context that expects glvalue(such as `t.rf = 0;`), in this time, `t.rf` is used as a glvalue, which should be determined what the entity it refer to.  that is `the result of glvalue`.

Comment: I remember I was gonna to file an editorial issue about this but never actually did xD

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think it's a vague in [expr.ref], as I said in the question. The section specified what the value category is(For the entire postfix expression) and these rules implies what's the entity such `postfix expression` denote for most situations. However, it does not specify what's the entity denoted by `E1.E2` where `E2` is of reference type. It just specifies the value category and type for such `postfix expression`, but there's no rule implies what' the entity such expression denotes. Could you link your editorial issue.

Comment: _Could you link your editorial issue_ I wrote that I didn't file it. (But wanted long time ago).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer All right. So, you agree with me that this is a defect in [expr.ref], Right?(what's the entity of `E1.E2` where `E2` is of reference type, which determines the result of glvalue).

Comment: It shouldn't even be entity, it should say smth like "object or function to which the reference was bound".

Comment: @LanguageLawyer It could be called an entity due to The result of a **glvalue** is the **entity denoted by the expression**. In other words, for lvalue `E1.E2`(where `E2` is of reference type), when evaluating such an expression to determine the identity of an object, bit-field, or function.(which is the result of glvalue, namely, entity).

Comment: object (and value) shouldn't be "entity" (but this is not 100% sure)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  There's a relevant rule in [basic#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#3),  `An entity is a value, object, reference, function...`, So I think an object should be `entity`(I'm not sure whether I read it correctly).